# Smallest mouse controller

Tags: mouse, game-controller, trackpoint

I am a simple programer, exploring out from my usual space for the sake of curiosity and development so please bear with me. First if I am in the wrong exchange then please guide me in the right direction.

How small(in terms of height) can a [pointing stick/Nub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointing_stick) be? Is there a noticeable relation with height and its sensitivity/accuracy?

Comment: I've never ground one down to check, but since a trackpoint operates by sensing mechanical force applied in a given direction, it would seem to follow that shortening the stick would reduce the amount of force applied on the strain gauge for a given finger input, thus reducing the sensitivity of the device.

Comment: sounds like an engineering question to me, but yes I agree with aaron. Imagine if the stick was made super long, and the rest stayed the same. Then the slightest nudge would send the pointer going fast. But if you enlarged the whole trackpoint thing, including whatever is at the base of it, then it'd be the same.  Maybe it works similarly to a joystick, but consider a joystick. With a joystick , the base was big so it didn't matter that the stick was big, but also you could amend the sensitivity with software.